# Finding sum of sequence: $1, 2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5.......$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$1, 2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,\ldots ,n$ $(n$ times$)$

**Approach:**

> Observation: For summation, let us consider a term $t_x$ as the sum of the terms which follow a general order.

Like:

$$t_1 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+\ldots+n$$

$$t_2 = 2+3+4+5+6+\ldots+n$$

$$t_3 = 3+4+5+6+\ldots+n$$

$$.$$

$$.$$

$$.$$

$$t_{n-1} = n -1 + n$$

$$t_n = n$$

For complete summation, we need to add all the $t_x$ obtained from the above.

For this particular step, I am getting a really big and lengthy sigma, which I am not able to evaluate.

$$\sum_{n=1}^n  t_n$$

Now each term $t_n$ comprises of a summation of its very own.

$$\sum t_n = \sum_{n=k}^n \cfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

where $k= 1,2,3,\ldots,n$.

What to do next? After plugging in values for $k$, I am getting a really ugly expression. Please help.

---

P.S: This question might have been asked before, but I want to solve it through the above mentioned method. So please don’t mark it as duplicate and close it.

Comment: Note that this is the same as the sum of the first $n$ squares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the expression of the sum is a polynomial in $n$, let $P(n)$.

Now if you set the last terms apart,

$$P(n)-P(n-1)=\underbrace{n+n+n\cdots n}_n=n^2.$$

This shows that the polynomial must be of degree $3$.

By direct computation, we have

$$P(0)=0,P(1)=1,P(2)=5,P(3)=14$$ and the Lagrangian interpolation polynomial by these four points is (after tedious direct computation or by identification*)

$$P(n)=\frac{n^3}3+\frac{n^2}2+\frac{n}6.$$

We can now confirm

$$P(n)-P(n-1)=\frac{3n^2-3n+1}3+\frac{2n-1}2+\frac16=n^2.$$

---

*With $P(n)=an^3+bn^2+cn+d$, we perform Gaussian elimination
$$d=0,\\a+b+c=1,\\8a+4b+2c=5,\\27a+9b+3c=14$$

$$6a+2b=3,\\24a+6b=11$$

$$6a=2$$
$$2b=1$$

$$c=1-\frac12-\frac13$$